# How to calculate $x_{n}= \sqrt{n+ \sqrt{n- 1+ \sqrt{n- 2+ \sqrt{\cdots + \sqrt{2+ \sqrt{1}}}}}}$ without using surd signs

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, approximation, continued-fractions, nested-radicals

> How to calculate:
> $$x_{n}= \sqrt{n+ \sqrt{n- 1+ \sqrt{n- 2+ \sqrt{\cdots + \sqrt{2+ \sqrt{1}}}}}}$$
> without using surd signs.

My attempt:
I saw that
$$x^{2}_{n}= n+ x_{n- 1}$$
Therefore
$$x= 1+ \frac{n}{x}$$
So
$$x= 1+ \frac{n}{1+ \frac{n- 1}{1+ \frac{n- 2}{1+ \frac{n- 3}{\ddots }}}}$$
But it seems like no much useful for small $n.$ I need to your helps to get it. Thanks a real lot !

Comment: So $x_n^2=n+(n-1+x_{n-2})=\ldots=n+(n-1)+(n-2)+\ldots+2+x_1$ with $x_1=1$ if I understand correctly the original expression.

Comment: No,$$x^{2}_{n}= n+ x_{n+ 1}= n+ \sqrt{n- 1+ x_{n- 2}}$$

Comment: what is $x$, is it still $x_n$?

Comment: Are you asking to find the limit of that thing?

Comment: No, I'm just finding the value of it by none of surd signs

Comment: It's bounded above by the infinite sequence with $n$ in each spot, which is $\frac12+\sqrt{n+1/4}$

Comment: @empy2I'm sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can't apply the limit to

$$x_n^2=n+x_{n-1} \ \ (1)$$

to find the limit of $(x_n)$ because you have the divergent term $n$.

Note that

$$ \forall n,\ x_n >0 $$

So from $(1)$ you get

$$ \forall n , \ x_n > \sqrt{n}$$

**So the sequence diverges.**

**Secondly** closed form doesn't match well with the combination of plus sign and square-root so it is very unlikely to find an easier closed form.

Comment: The question asks for a *closed form* for $x_n$.

Comment: @Tavish's right